# I Want to Clarify whether Following answer Correct or Not?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
 int sum(int A[], int n)
 {
    int sum = 0, i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum = sum + A[i];
    return sum;
 }

      'n*2' bytes of memory to store array variable 'a[]'
      2 bytes of memory for integer parameter 'n'
      4 bytes of memory for local integer variables 'sum' and 'i' (2 bytes 
       each)
      2 bytes of memory for return value.

      Total space Needed = 2n + 8
```

let assume c compiler takes 2 bytes for store integer value

I want to know whether above calculated total space answer is correct or not?
I have doubt in return statement because i first allocate memory to sum variable and sum is return last so i need to no whether return sum statement needed memory allocation.

Comment: Since this algorithm is coded in C, I'd suggest to tag it also appropriately.

Comment: _"I Want to Clarify whether Following answer Correct or Not?"_ You should tell us what the **question** was... It seems like it was something like 'How many bytes of stack space does this function need', but as is, it seems too vague. "Total space Needed" is not really a concept that makes sense here, since memory usage has many forms and fluctuations, both spatial and temporal.

Comment: Question wad to calculate space complexity?   Below the question show how i calculate it

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear.  Is it about an *algorithm*, with the C code functioning essentially as pseudocode, or is it asking about the C semantics of the code presented?  If the latter, then is the point to consider only the *additional* storage required by the function, or are you to include the storage used by its caller (which you have not described)?  Are you supposed to take calling conventions into account?  If so, what *are* the conventions?

Comment: Why is int using 2 bytes of memory? It uses 4 on most modern 32 and 64 bits systems. You should probably check the sizeof macro. Also you are considering the return value, does that means you want to check the compiler as well? If so you are missing some stuff (parameters are copied as well, for instance).

Comment: @FernandoCoelho If it is explicitely stated to use 2 bytes, it doesn't really matter what most machines do. The world does not only consist of desktop machines. On my XC167 µC boards the integers are still 16 bits. Same as they were 10 years ago. ;) BTW: The OP did take memory for parameters into account. Not really in a correct way, though.

Comment: @Gerhardh I just wanted him to be sure, since it is very uncommon. Also, I would rather that he had used sizeof(int) in the formula, as someone may come here in the future and get confused.

Answer (score 1):

ASSUMING -> the posed question was about how much stack space this function will require:

Well, the `A[]` parameter is not an array; it's a pointer to the first element of the array, so that's `sizeof(int*)`, not `n * sizeof(int)`.

Whether you need space for the return value depends on whether your environment returns integers in CPU registers, or pushes them onto the stack. If on the stack, then yes, you need to allow for that space.

---

ASSUMING -> the posed question was about BigO space complexity

Caveat: How you calculate space complexity for an algorithm depends LARGELY on the programming language and / or hardware environment. Contrast this with time complexity, which is mostly language / hardware agnostic. Be advised that most examples for space complexity on the web make some pretty bald assumptions.

For example, the `A[]` parameter in this example is almost always assumed to consume the space required for every element in the array. In C, and languages that pass object references, this is simply not true. In some of the web examples, this is mentioned in a footnote; in others, not at all.

So, for this post, the answer for BigO space complexity is -> It Depends. It could either be O(1) or O(n), depending on who's asking and where it's expected to run.

Comment: Passing data via registers might also be applied to function parameters.

Comment: @Gerhardh: I concur, although I suspect the scope of the question was more limited than that (smells kinda like homework). I really only mentioned register return to illustrate that it wasn't specified in the OP.